# Acronyms, index "see" and auxiliary files

Tags: glossaries, indexing, acronyms, auxiliary-files

I'm using a few acronyms in my thesis, and I want them to appear in the alphabetical index as:

> ACR, see acronym
>
> acronym, iii, 5, 48

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{bookmark} % includes hyperref
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeindex[intoc]
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{fmea}{FMEA}{Fail\-ure Mode and Ef\-fect A\-nal\-y\-sis}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter
    Occurrence of the acronym \acrlong{FMEA}
    \index{FMEA}
    
    \backmatter
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist]
    \index{failure mode and effect analysis|see{FMEA}}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

This code works perfectly but I have to declare each acronym twice (as newacronym and as index "see").
I introduced this command as a variant of `\newacronym` which also generates the corresponding `\index` voice:

```
\newcommand{\newacronymidx}[3]{
  \newacronym{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \index{\MakeLowercase{#3}|see #2}
}

\newacronym{fmea}{FMEA}{Fail\-ure Mode and Ef\-fect A\-nal\-y\-sis}
```

I have three problems:

1. the "ACR, see acronym" index entry appears at the beginning of the alphabetical index instead of its correct alphabetically-sorted position
2. now I get a page number after "ACR, see acronym", whose hyperlink refers to first page (the frontispiece, not included in this MWE)
3. for some weird reason I can't understand, FMEA becomes FEA (which does not appear anywhere in my code)

[image: Screenshot of the index]

In this example, FMEA is defined with `\newacronymidx`, other acronyms with \newacronym and \index{acronym|see ACR}. The only wrong one is FMEA.

**Question 1:**

I think that the first two problems are related to the position of the `\index` command in the source (which is now in the preamble). Is there any way to create an auxiliary files, use `\makeacronymidx` to append a new line with the `\index` command to this file, and use `\include{myAuxFile}` right before `\printindex`?

**Question 2:**

Any idea about FMEA becoming FEA in the index? This does not happen with this MWE, but I can't post the full code here...

Thank you!

**EDIT: solved by Nicola Talbot in the comments**

```
\newcommand{\newacronymidx}[3]{
  \newacronym{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \index{#3@\MakeLowercase{#3}|see {#2}}
}
```

Comment: Your definition of `\newacronymidx` is missing braces for the `see` argument: `\index{\MakeLowercase{#3}|see #2}` should be `\index{\MakeLowercase{#3}|see{#2}}` (which accounts for Question 2, `M` is treated as the second argument which is ignored).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the obvious solution to the main part of the question. You need to specify the actual (sort) part: `\index{#3@\MakeLowercase{#3}|see{#2}}`. (Pretty sure this is a dup.)

Comment: Thank you, now everything works fine. So the first problem was due to the fact that the entry was sorted under "\" instead of "f", is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary of comments:

- A sort value is required when the indexed term contains formatting commands (as `makeindex` doesn't ignore LaTeX commands but treats them as a string starting with `\`).
- The `see` encap requires braces around the argument: `|see FMEA` becomes `\see FMEA{1}` which is effectively `\see{F}{M}EA1`, so the `M` is discarded and the page number appears.

So the definition needs to be:

```
\newcommand{\newacronymidx}[3]{%
  \newacronym{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \index{#3@\MakeLowercase{#3}|see{#2}}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this could be helpful to anyone, here are two ways to index acronyms, with the corrections made by Nicola Talbot. This code allows to specify the sorting part as optional argument.

---

**Method 1:** acronym points to full text

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\newacronymidx}[4][]{ % rimanda acronimo a esteso
    \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}
        { \index{#3|see{\MakeLowercase{#4}}} }
        { \index{#3|see{#1}} }
}

\newacronymidx{acr}{ACR}{Acronym}
\newacronymidx[qwerty]{abb}{ABB}{Abbreviation}
```

> INDEX:
>   ABB, *see* qwerty
>   ACR, *see* acronym
>   acronym, 18
>   qwerty, 36, 58

A possible use could be:

```
\newacronymidx[control limits]{ucl}{UCL}{Upper Control Limit}
```

Index entry: UCL, *see* control limits

---

**Method 2:** full text points to acronym

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\newacronymidx}[4][]{ % rimanda esteso ad acronimo
    \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}
    { \index{#4@\MakeLowercase{#4}|see{#3}} }
    { \index{#1|see{#3}} }
}

\newacronymidx{acr}{ACR}{Acronym}
\newacronymidx[qwerty]{abb}{ABB}{Abbreviation}
```

> INDEX:
>   ABB, 36, 58
>   ACR, 18
>   acronym, *see* ACR
>   qwerty, *see* ABB

A possible use could be:

```
\newacronymidx[Western Electric rules]{wer}{WER}{Western Electric Rules}
```

Index entry: Western Electric rules, *see* WER

(I don't want Western Electric to be lowercased)